# Audio file validation on voyager-laravel

Tags: laravel, voyager

I need to validate audio files in bread, using laravel voyager, this is my code, but it doesn't works

```
{
    "validation": {
        "rule": [
            "required",
            "mimetypes:audio/x-wav"
        ]
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

Select as input-type `Media Picker`.

Add the following options to your input field.

```php
{
    "allowed": [
        "audio"
    ]
}
```

Here are some more options [Laravel Voyager](https://voyager-docs.devdojo.com/bread/introduction-1/media-picker).

Comment: Hi, thanks for your post, but I've tried that and it doesn't work. I am trying to make a custom Formfields as Voyager says.

Comment: I've revised my answer, check it out, please.

Comment: The Media Picker, is not stored in the bd field